# Python OrderedDict not keeping element order

Tags: python, python-2.7, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to create an OrderedDict object but no sooner do I create it, than the elements are all jumbled.

This is what I do:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict({(0,0):[2],(0,1):[1,9],(0,2):[1,5,9]})
```

The elements don't stay in the order I assign

```
od
OrderedDict([((0, 1), [1, 9]), ((0, 0), [2]), ((0, 2), [1, 5, 9])])
```

docs.python.org doesn't have an example and I can't figure out why the order is getting jumbled. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Your problem is that you are constructing a `dict` to give the initial data to the `OrderedDict` - this `dict` *doesn't* store any order, so the order is lost before it gets to the `OrderedDict`.

The solution is to build from an ordered data type - the easiest being a `list` of `tuple`s:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict([((0, 0), [2]), ((0, 1), [1, 9]), ((0, 2), [1, 5, 9])])
>>> od
OrderedDict([((0, 0), [2]), ((0, 1), [1, 9]), ((0, 2), [1, 5, 9])])
```

It's worth noting that this is why `OrderedDict` uses the syntax it does for it's string representation - string representations should try to be valid Python code to reproduce the object where possible, and that's why the output uses a list of tuples instead of a dict.

Edit: [As of Python 3.6, `kwargs` is ordered](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-468-preserving-keyword-argument-order), so you can use keyword arguments instead, provided you are on an up-to-date Python version.

[As of 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html), this is also true for `dict`s (it was for CPython in 3.6, but the language spec didn't specify it, so using `OrderedDict` was still required for compatibility). This means if you can assume a 3.7+ environment, you can often drop `OrderedDict` altogether, or construct one from a regular `dict` if you need a specific feature (e.g: order to matter for equality).

Comment: Also of note, passing names/values to the constructor isn't enough to set the order.
`>>> from collections import OrderedDict`
`>>> OrderedDict(one=1, two=2, three=3, four=4)`
`OrderedDict([('four', 4), ('one', 1), ('three', 3), ('two', 2)])`

Comment: @EricSmith Indeed, for the same reason - variable keyword args (`**kwargs`) in Python are stored as a dictionary - so when that happens, the order is lost as before. Note that [PEP-468](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/) has a simple solution to this - use an `OrderedDict` for `kwargs`, not a feature yet, but maybe some day.

Comment: @GarethLatty now in [python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-468-preserving-keyword-argument-order) they implemented PEP-468